# How do I Efficiently Chain Channels Together?

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm trying to create message hub in golang. Messages are getting through different channels that persist in `map[uint32]chan []float64`. I do an endless loop over map and check if a channel has a message. If it has, I write it to the common client's write channel together with an incoming channel's id. It works fine, but uses all CPU, and other processes are throttled.

UPD: Items in map adding and removing dynamically by another function.

I thinking to limit CPU for this app through Docker, but maybe there is more elegant path?

My code :

```
    func (c *Client) accumHandler() {

    for !c.stop {
        c.channels.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {

            select {
            case message := <-value.(chan []float64):
                mess := map[uint32]interface{}{key.(uint32): message}

                select {
                case c.send <- mess:

                }

            default:

            }
            return !c.stop
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have 100% cpu usage with no messages, you have a busy loop somewhere. What does "channel.Range()" do? Why do you have a select with 1 case? Your stop condition looks suspect, and possibly racy. Can you create an [mcve]?

Comment: Well, my busy loop is `case message := <-value.(chan []float64):` and I think about what can I do with it, channel.Range is a library function for `sync.Map` to iterate over items, select with case-default is go pattern for non-blocking reading. I'll try to create tiny example and update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading the cards correctly, it seems like you are trying to pass along an array of floats to a common channel along with a channel identifier.  I assume that you are doing this to pass multiple channels out to different publishers, but so that you only have to track a single channel for your consumer.

It turns out that you don't need to loop over channels to see when it's outputting a value.  You can chain channels together inside of goroutines.  For this reason, no busy wait is necessary.  Something like this will suit your purposes (again, if I'm reading the cards correctly).  Look for the all caps comment for the way around your busy loop.  [Link to playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1nVNGw1Z7xH).

```
var num_publishes = 3

func main() {
  num_publishers := 10
  single_consumer := make(chan []float64)

  for i:=0;i<num_publishers;i+=1 {
    c := make(chan []float64)

    // connect channel to your single consumer channel
    go func() { for { single_consumer <- <-c } }() // THIS IS PROBABLY WHAT YOU DIDN'T KNOW ABOUT

    // send the channel to the publisher
    go publisher(c, i*100)
  }

  // dumb consumer example
  for i:=0;i<num_publishers*num_publishes;i+=1 {
    fmt.Println(<-single_consumer)
  }
}

func publisher(c chan []float64, publisher_id int) {
  dummy := []float64{
    float64(publisher_id+1),
    float64(publisher_id+2),
    float64(publisher_id+3),
  }
  for i:=0;i<num_publishes;i+=1 {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(10000)) * time.Millisecond)
    c <- dummy
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, i don't know capsed trick really ! I missed one important thing - items in map adding and removing dynamically by another function (added this to question), so if a publisher go out - what can i do with linked goroutine?

Comment: It's good idea to change channels to goroutines in dictionary and pushing client channel in it blocking. Thx Frank, problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It is eating all of your CPU because you are continuously cycling around the dictionary checking for messages, so even when there are no messages to process the CPU, or at least a thread or core, is running flat out. You need blocking sends and receives on the channels!

I assume you are doing this because you don't know how many channels there will be and therefor can't just `select` on all of the input channels. A better pattern would be to start a separate goroutine for each input channel you are currently storing in the dictionary. Each goroutine should have a loop in which it blocks waiting the input channel and on receiving a message does a blocking send to a channel to the client which is shared by all.

The question isn't complete so can't give exact code, but you're going to have goroutines that look something like this:

```
type Message struct {
    id uint32,
    message []float64
}

func receiverGoroutine(id uint32, input chan []float64, output chan Message) {
    for {
        message := <- input
        output <- Message{id: id, message: message}
    }
}

func clientGoroutine(c *Client, input chan Message) {
    for {
        message := <- input
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

(You'll need to add some "done" channels as well though)

Elsewhere you will start them with code like this:

```
clientChan := make(chan Message)
go clientGoroutine(client, clientChan)

for i:=0; i<max; i++ {
    go receiverGoroutine( (uint32)i, make(chan []float64, clientChan)
}
```

Or you can just start the client routine and then add the others as they are needed rather than in a loop up front - depends on your use case.

Comment: Thx for idea, and you are right - i don't now map capacity, furthermore - items in dictionary may add and remove on air.  If I create a goroutine for each item how can i kill them when item removes?